# showing data graphically in asp.net 3.5 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

i am using asp.net 3.5 framework to develop an application.I got a requirement of showing the data in a graphical format where 3.5 i not embedded with graphs.I googled and found out way to get charts control to 3.5 framework.I am new to this.I need to show data in different charts available in the framework.how to get data from database and project data on to the graphs

Kindly help in this regard.

Comment: I don't understand that question to be honest. Are you asking how show graphs when .NET 3.5 isn't on the client? It only needs to be on the server so it isn't an issue.

Maybe you could clarify the question so we can help more

Comment: Can you show me a simple graph how's your shape is ?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31858/ASP-NET-Charting-Controls Check this link for example. Things are explained there.

Comment: i am able to show the graph when i am hardcoding the the values.I need to show data on graph where the values are varying dynamically.I need help in this regard.My requirement is showing Pie Charts

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, what you are basically asking is how to data bind the chart control. Again assuming you have a table in the database which has columns that you would like to display in a chart.
There are several ways to set the data source, one way would be

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(myTable.DefaultView, "myColumnName1", myTable.DefaultView, "myColumnName2";
```

where `myColumnName1` is for the X axis and `myColumnName2` is for the Y axis. 
Now once you have done this you must bind the data to the chart.

```
chart1.DataBind();
```

Now your chart will display the values of the selected columns in the chart. For a comprehensive review please refer [DataBinding MS Chart](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx)